# How to draw the 2D canvas drawing of top view of Threejs scene?

Tags: three.js

i created the simple demo app like room design. in which i generated the floor with 2 walls and on the floor there are multiple boxes.
i want to create 2D view of that scene.
i just want to know from where to start.

I tried to do the R&D and tried to draw it with scene values but it's not working for me.